# Optimal Performance: SVG vs JPG for E-Commerce

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, svg, e-commerce

Department>Category> 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc OR an SVG
In a Category I gotta load <~100 images, what would be better a set of JPEG's fetched by filenames or is any way around where I can pre-load an SVG and serve the thumbnail images from it as I suppose that would save us a lot of loading calls to the server.
Also what is the optimal image format to use for images.

P.s. I'm using MEAN Stack with Bootstrap.

Comment: image works on every browsers without extra effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think probably the best way to go is to not use SVG at all.  Instead get all of your jpg images combined into one file and use css image sprites.  That way by loading one image you will load all of the individual images at one go.  It will be very efficient and you will still have access to each image individually.

Comment: Forgive me for my illiteracy, I meant CSS Sprites but dint know the term..you've explained my problem better than me..

Comment: If at all I use sprites, would I have the same amount of freedom considering i'm using AngularJS in all its ng-repeat, etc glory.

Comment: Try this: http://csssprites.com/   This site will let you upload all of your images and it will automatically generate what you need. If your input images have predictable names like pic1.jpg, pic2.jpg, pic3.jpg it will be very easy to address them in an ng-repeat directive.  The csssprites tool shows you how to access each image and you can download and save what it generates for you.

Comment: Thanks alot..can you also suggest me the best lossless way to compress images for web and also the optimal format of the image file..?